# Once camera angle is locked into place with location rotation, how do I delete?

Tags: camera, edit-mode, scene

I'm editing a video and I locked my camera angles in with "locroc" but now I want to delete a few of the angles and I'm not sure how. I tried the undo button but it won't go back enough times to erase the ones I want to get rid of. How can I delete them?

Comment: In the dope sheet editor (or the graph editor) delete the keyframes you don't need.

Comment: Are you referring to keyframes?

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by selecting the camera then pressing these buttons:

[image]